# Area of a rectangle.

Tags: geometry

What is the area of a rectangle that measures 4/10 x 4Ft.  My grandson's teacher says the answer is squared = 1 2/5 squared

Comment: It would help to be clear about the units of measurement.  Both sides of the rectangle should have "length".

Comment: Also is 1 2/5 supposed to be a mixed number?

Answer (score 4):

Area of rectangle = length * width

$\frac{4*4}{10} = \frac{16}{10} = \frac{8}{5} = 1 \frac{3}{5}$

Units are feet squared, so

$1 \frac{3}{5} $ $ft^2 $ is the correct answer.